# sending email through firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a react, javascript, firebase app that I need to send out a welcome email to clients when they sign up for my app, but only after they pay. firebase seems to allow me to send out emails, but is there code I can put in my success function that allows me to trigger the email when I want, instead of when a user registers using the auth functionality in firebase?

Comment: Check out this https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [firebase extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) but you must be on the [Blaze plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)

here is an example of how use a trigger

```
admin.firestore().collection('mail').add({
  to: 'someone@example.com',
  message: {
    subject: 'Hello from Firebase!',
    html: 'This is an <code>HTML</code> email body.',
  },
})
```